# WSO2 ESB not serialize JMS (ActiveMQ) with local transport

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm using WSO2 ESB 4.6.0, and I've tried to use local transport with this
[example](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB460/Local+Transport).

I have no problem with `Send` mediator if it uses HTTP.

With 'local transport' everything works well, except using JMS between proxies, then the exception below is triggered.

```
Unexpected error during sending message out
{org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender} 
java.lang.NullPointerException 
at org.wso2.carbon.message.store.persistence.jms.util.JMSPersistentMessageHelper.createPersistentMessage(JMSPersistentMessageHelper.java:221)
```

An example of my test:

Proxy01:

```
<send>
    <endpoint>
       <address uri="local://services/Proxy02" format="soap11"/>
    </endpoint>
</send>
```

Proxy02:

```
<send>
    <endpoint>
         <address uri="local://services/Proxy03_MessageStore" format="soap11"/>
    </endpoint>
</send>
```

Proxy03_MessageStore

```
<property name="target.endpoint" value="EndPoint"/>
<store messageStore="MessageStore"/>
```

Message Store

```
<messageStore xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
name="MessageStore" class="org.wso2.carbon.message.store.persistence.jms.JMSMessageStore">
<parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial">org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory</parameter>
<parameter name="store.jms.cache.connection">false</parameter>
<parameter name="java.naming.provider.url">tcp://IP_SERVER:61616</parameter>
<parameter name="store.jms.ConsumerReceiveTimeOut">0</parameter>
<parameter name="store.jms.JMSSpecVersion">1.1</parameter>
<parameter name="store.jms.destination">queueName</parameter>
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the upgrade to the ESB 4.9.0 version and I solved my problem.